# how to extend a jQuery slider's functionality

Tags: jquery

[image: jQuery Slider]I've got a working jQuery slider but I have to add a bit of functionality to display a rotating title below the thumbnails. I've gone through five attempts and nothing has worked fully. How do I add the attribute "active" to the class "ctitle" with the same rotation pattern as the thumbs. Any guru's out there willing to help me extend my understanding of jQuery?

I've added the code to a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/julianmiller/vJZEQ/ (forgive it's sloppiness. I had to pull it out of a proprietary language framework)

Comment: I am assuming each title will be unique to the image. Is this correct? If so you will need to figure out which image is playing to ensure it receives the proper caption.

Comment: that is correct. there is a specific call to the title for each image and it's all generated dynamically. The code itself simply represents those calls and i need to task jQuery with adding the "active" style to the dynamic title as the corresponding image is highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your slideshow / intentions. But what I think what you want to do is determine which slide is active and then add a corresponding caption.

```
function addCaption() {


if($('.words li').hasClas('active')) {
  $(this).html('<p>Your caption </p>');
}


}
```

Now this will add the same caption to all images with the class active. If you want only the ones with the class ctitle to have the caption then you would change "active" to "ctitle".

However, if you are looking to add captions based on which image is loaded then that is a bit more complicated. Before I try to tackle that I am wondering if you can tell me this. Are the images dynamically loaded? Do you know how many images there are? Or is this all hard coded?

Comment: Wow. this is already helping a ton. There will always be 4 images and they will be dynamically loaded.

Comment: Do you have access to the database for these images. Where are the images coming from if you don't mind me asking. Are they stored in a MYSQL table somewhere? Or are you using something like Flickr?

Comment: they are generated by tags inside of a CMS system. essentially <li><%image:tag%></li> sits inside of a div and all the jquery acts upon is those to render and rotate the active state.

Comment: Okay well from a jQuery perspective there really is no elegant way to do this. Technically if you know what all of the images are and the exact order you could hand jam all of the captions in with some code. But ideally I would add them into the database and feed them out the same way as the images.

Comment: did you get a chance to look at the jquery/javascript in the jsfiddle? they do it there for the thumbnails. I'm just not sure how to replicate it.

Comment: Yeah I did. I am not really sure I am seeing the whole picture though. Do you have a URL I can look at?

Comment: There must be another PHP script or JS file generating the images. You will need to find out where the images are coming from and then find out if there are captions you can pull. Otherwise you are going to have to add them and create a new script to insert them into your HTML. It looks like the plugin you are using came from here. http://codecanyon.net/item/spider-thumbnail-slider-a-creative-jquery-slider/852859 And because it is a paid for plugin there is no documentation on how to use the titles. I wish I could help you more, but this is beyond my level of access.